# Spring TransactionalEventListener dose not work for Map or HashMap

Tags: spring, events, spring-transactions

I want to send email after transaction complete . I decide to  use TransactionalEventListener for do this ,my listener is like this

```
@TransactionalEventListener
void sendEmailAndSMS(Map<String,Object> params);
```

and my publisher is like this

```
Map<String,Object> params=new HashMap<>();
params.put("eventName","sendEmailAndSmsForCreateUser");
params.put("user",user);
params.put("templateName","CreateUser");
publisher.publishEvent(params);
```

when i change listener to this work correct

```
@TransactionalEventListener
void sendEmailAndSMS(User user);
```

Why dose not work in Map ?!!

Comment: `publisher.publishEvent(user)` is this typo or you are really doing this and expecting the listener to trigger. Because you are sending user and you are listening on map

Comment: sorry my question body is wrong i change that . i send params and dose not work